# Override function

Tags: ios, swift

I am taking a iOS course online provided by a famous university. I don't understand why the following code use `override` and it is legal.

1. According to the official definition, we use `override` to override superclass' methods. Where is the subclass and superclass in the following code?
2. What's been override and by what?

> ```
> public override var description: String {
>     return "\(url.absoluteString) (aspect ratio = \(aspectRatio))"
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you show the `Class` where you are writing this function?

Comment: You can "override" methods in order to provide a custom behavior.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is an example:

Your original class:

```
class Person {
    func walk() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Your subclass:

```
class Runner: Person {
    override func walk() {
        //do something that is different from Person's walk
    }
}
```

In the `Runner` class, there is an `override` with the function `walk`. That is because it is a subclass of `Person`, and it can override Person's walk function. So If you instantiate a `Runner`:

```
var usainBolt = Runner()
```

And you call the `walk` function:

```
usainBolt.walk()
```

Then that will call the overriden function that you wrote in the `Runner` class. If you don't override it, it will call the `walk` function that you wrote in `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

> According to the official definition, we use override to override superclass' methods.

That's correct. The superclass in your example is the class that encloses the override of `description` property. This could be `NSObject`, some other class derived from it (directly or indirectly), or some class unrelated to `NSObject` that has `var description: String` property.

`description` is a property that Swift classes commonly have as a way to present themselves as a string, because `description` provides conformance to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. This is similar to `toString()` method of Java, and to `str()` method of Python.

> What's been override and by what?

The implementation of the property is what's being overridden. The class that has the implementation does the overriding.