# Swift extension of Array<MutableCollection> won't allow reverse()

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods, swift-playground

I am attempting to extend `Array<MutatingCollection>` so I can mirror the contents of an Array of Arrays, but the compiler says I can't call `reverse()` on the elements in the array, despite `reverse()` being defined in `MutatingCollection` protocol.

I want to do something like this:

```
var table = [[0,1,2],
             [3,4,5],
             [6,7,8]]
table.mirror()
//table now [[2,1,0],
//           [5,4,3],
//           [8,7,6]]
```

Here is my (not working) code:

```
 extension Array where Element == MutableCollection {
        mutating func mirror() {
            for index in self.indices {
                self[index].reverse()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried it as `self.map {array in array.reverse()}` as well (which I *think* does the same thing, but I don't fully grok `map()`) Both ways result in the same error message:

`Member 'reverse' cannot be used on value of type 'MutableCollection'`

Edit: I can call the same code directly and it works as I intended.

[Playgrounds Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cDii.jpg)

Perhaps I'm using `extension` improperly, or Swift Playgrounds is blocking my access somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the extension should be declared like this:

```
extension Array where Element : MutableCollection {
```

You want to check that `Element` adheres to the protocol `MutableCollection`, not that it is a `MutableCollection`

However, then I'm not able to call the `reverse` method on the `subscript` for some reason. The best I've been able to do is this:

```
extension Array where Element : MutableCollection {
  mutating func mirror() {
    for index in self.indices {
      self[index] = self[index].reversed() as! Element
    }
  }
}
```

Which works as you need it to work although the forced cast is very ugly and I dislike doing it. I suppose I should test the cast to be certain but I can't see any case where calling `reversed()` would result in a collection that couldn't be cast back to `Element`.

Edit:

I figured out the issue. The `reverse()` method is only valid on `MutableCollection` when it is also a `BidirectionalCollection`. This code now works correctly:

```
extension MutableCollection where
  Iterator.Element : MutableCollection &
                     BidirectionalCollection,
  Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
  mutating func mirror() {
    for index in self.indices {
      self[index].reverse()
    }
  }
}
```

Now the code should work for all `MutableCollection` whose elements are both a `MutableCollection` and `BidirectionalCollection` - such as `[Array<Int>]` or even `[ArraySlice<Int>]`

You can see the full code for `reverse()` in Swift 3.1 here:

[Reverse.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-3.1-branch/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift)

> extension MutableCollection where Self : BidirectionalCollection

Comment: This crashes if `Element` is a mutable collection but not an array, e.g. for `var table = [[0,1,2].dropFirst(), [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]`, where `Element` is `ArraySlice<Int>`.

Comment: @MartinR I believe I've nailed down the cause for the issue posed in this question, as well as correcting for the issue you mentioned. Please feel free to check its correctness for me.

Comment: With an additional constraint `Indices.Iterator.Element == Index` you can get rid of the artificial `guard let index = index ...`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457590/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331858/1187415. It should not be necessary in Swift 4.

Comment: @MartinR Perfect! I was looking for the best way to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!